# How to store website content and name it with its own url?

Tags: java

I need your help. I created the code below, which stores the content from some websites on local hdd. The top_urls.txt contains a large number of websites.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{ 

 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( new  FileReader("top_urls.txt") );

try {

    String content = "contents_urls";
    int i=1;

Scanner freader = new Scanner(input);

while ( freader.hasNextLine() ) {

         String url = freader.nextLine();
         System.out.println(url);
         String out = new Scanner(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
         System.out.println(out);
         String file_name = content +i;
         PrintWriter pwout = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter ("site_"+ i+ ".txt",true) );
         pwout.println(out);    

         i++;
      }
    freader.close();

   } catch (IOException ex) {

     ex.printStackTrace();

 } System.out.println("Done"); 

}
```

So, when a website's content is storing the file is named site_1.txt, site_2.txt etc.
I want to store the content file with website name, eg. www.google.com.txt etc.

I tried 
`PrintWriter pwout = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter (url+".txt",true) );` , but doesn't work.
Any ideas how to do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? That's the right idea; so tell us what the actual problem you're encountering is or we can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: A url like `http://google.com` when gets appended by txt, doesn't form a valid filename. Replace '/' and '.' with '_' and '-' or something like that

Comment: @HenryKeiter, the code works fine, but I want to to store the content like www.google.com.txt and not like site_1.txt. That's what I want to do. Thanks

Comment: @Yon You say, "I tried `PrintWriter pwout = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter (url+".txt",true) );` , but doesn't work." What do you mean by this? Make sure you're taking out slashes and any other illegal filename characters, as others have suggested.

Comment: @HenryKeiter yeah, but I didn't do anything for slashes, I will try to fix it and take them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that your URLs are something like `http://www.example.com/foo.html`.  I don't think creating a filename containing the colon is going to work on many OSes (on windows it will probably try to parse `http` as a drive letter and fail, for example).

In which case you'd need to decide how you wanted the URL above to appear in the filename, and shorten it accordingly.  This might just be taking the domain between the `http://` prefix and the next slash, or it might be replacing all alphanumeric characters with underscores, or something else entirely.

Comment: A quick fix would be to just replace all illegal characters: `PrintWriter pwout = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter (url.replaceAll("[^-\\w.]", "_")+".txt",true) );`

Comment: @Andrzej, Thanks, I will try to do what you say.